# Cannot insert column NULL... but the value is not null

Tags: c#

Really, this couldn't be more simple. See on the screenshot, I get the error `Cannot insert null value into column ZoneID`. I don't get it because we clearly see that `ZoneID = 64`.

I've never seen that before, anyone has an explanation? I've retried many times with the same result.

Here is the code that breaks on `SubmitChanges`

```
var myZoneID = zone.ZoneID;
var x = clbCodesPostaux.CheckedItems.Cast<CodePostalShortItem>();
    foreach (var codesPostal in x)
    {
        var zoneCodePostal = new AssociationZonesCodesPostaux
                 {
                      CodePostalID = codesPostal.CodePostalID,
                      ZoneID = myZoneID
                 };
        using (var context = AccesDataRépart.GetNewContextRépart())
        {
                    context.AssociationZonesCodesPostaux.InsertOnSubmit(zoneCodePostal);
                    context.SubmitChanges();
        }
   }
```

EDIT: I refreshed the dbml mapping (removed and readded the table), but it didn't work.

[image]
[(Click for bigger image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBVQW.png)

Comment: Copy paste code and exceptions. Don't post screenshots

Comment: your screenshot is too small to read the error messages. Please show us your generated SQL or Linq code and the exception report in text.

Comment: Intercept the SQL being sent using SQL Profiler. Post it here. Are there triggers? Also, I advise you to uninstall all language packs. Makes it easier for you to get help.

Comment: For those of you that complain that the screenshot is too small.  You can always open the image in the browswer to check it out without the size constraints.  In the meantime that is.

Comment: Wow! Visual studio speaks French! How cool is that!!

Comment: Is it possible you are submitting a new empty record and not just the one we see here (en passant je parle francais... :)

Comment: @SerenityNow very good idea (because we are all guessing right now...) but the context is fresh. No other entity in it. My guess: instead-of trigger or unmapped field. Sometimes the guess-the-bug game is fun.

Comment: I wish I could get rid of the maddening French VS... good clue for the language pack

Comment: I had the same problem (vs french pack) at my new job.. good luck getting rid of it... I threw the computer out the window.. it worked

Comment: You should ensure that your mapping is set up properly and make sure that the property ZoneId is mapped to the database column ZoneId

Comment: Can you post the code for `AccesDataRépart.GetNewContextRépart()`? Also, non ascii characters in class and method names... i too like to live dangerously.